# Limit of a recursive sequences involving the AM, GM, and HM (arithmetic-geometric-harmonic mean)

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, recursion, average, means

Let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers. And let $\text{AM}$, $\text{GM}$, $\text{HM}$ respectively be the arithmetic mean, geometric mean, and harmonic mean.

Define 
$$a_n=\text{AM}(a_{n-1},g_{n-1},h_{n-1}),$$
$$g_n=\text{GM}(a_{n-1},g_{n-1},h_{n-1}),$$
$$h_n=\text{HM}(a_{n-1},g_{n-1},h_{n-1})$$

with
$a_0=x,$ $g_0=y,$ $h_0=z$.

I found that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} h_n$$

This is an analog of other mean combinations such as the [arithmetic-geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) and [geometric-harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric%E2%80%93harmonic_mean). The arithmetic-harmonic mean is just the geometric mean. Therefore this would be considered the arithmetic-geometric-harmonic mean (AGHM).

Indeed, an analogous identity as seen with the GHM seems to hold:
$$\text{AGHM}(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\text{AGHM}(\frac1x,\frac1y,\frac1z)}$$

But how do we prove these things? Maybe unlikely, but can we find a closed form for the AGHM?  Could the AGHM have any application?

*Interesting:*
I found from experimentation that $\text{AGHM}(x,y,\sqrt{xy})=\sqrt{xy}$.

Comment: Been playing with this. What do you think of $(x,y,z) = (1, -2, 4)$?

Comment: It seems you found a fixed point.  I excluded negatives because I knew they didn't converge together in general, but that is definitely an interesting special case.

Comment: It might be useful to limit your research to cases when $x=1$ since all the means are homogeneous, that is $M(cx, cy, cz) = cM(x, y, z)$.